# ESP32 Web Server Problem (Not triggering the function)

Tags: arduino, esp32

I want to open and close trigger using web server on ESP32,everything seems to be ok but it doesnt tring the function, what am i doing wrong, I dont need a web page for it, I just want to trig it via link  ;

This is the link i am trying to trigger function from my pc;
http://esp-ip-address/up

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define MZ80_ENTER  32
#define MZ80_EXIT  33
#define SERVO_ENTER 22
#define SERVO_EXIT 23

int enter_flag = 1, exit_flag = 0;

Servo servo_enter;
Servo servo_exit;


const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "pass";

WebServer server (80);

bool state = false;

void setup (){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(MZ80_ENTER, INPUT);
  pinMode(MZ80_EXIT, INPUT);
  servo_enter.attach(SERVO_ENTER);
  servo_exit.attach(SERVO_EXIT);
  servo_enter.write(0);
  delay(100);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/up", handleup);
  server.on("/down", handledown);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Web Server Running !");
  delay(150);
}

void loop(){
  server.handleClient(); 
  if (state){
    if (digitalRead (MZ80_ENTER) == 0 && enter_flag == 1) {
      servo_enter.write(100); 
      servo_exit.write(0);
      exit_flag = 1;
      enter_flag == 0;
      Serial.println ("Up");
      delay(500);
    }
  }
  else{
    if (digitalRead (MZ80_EXIT) == 0 && exit_flag == 1) {
      servo_exit.write(100); 
      servo_enter.write(0); 
      enter_flag = 1;
      exit_flag == 0;
      Serial.println ("Down");
      delay(500);
    } 
  }  
}

String answer = "Web Loaded !";


void handleRoot(){
  server.send(200,"text/html",answer); 
}

void handleup(){
  state = true ; 
  server.send(200,"text/html",answer); 
}

void handledown(){
  state = false ;
  server.send(200,"text/html",answer); 
}

void handleNotFound(){
  server.send(404,"text/html","Error 404 NOT FOUND");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just set state to true in setup does it trigger the way you want it to? If it doesn’t then it’s a problem with all the conditions you placed in addition to state, and not a problem with the web server.

Comment: It doesnt even print in serial monitor.

Comment: You have `WiFi.begin(ssid, password);` but you didn't wait for Wifi to be connected with `while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { }` which could take up to 6 seconds before you can proceed to run the server.

Answer (score 0):

You must wait for the wifi to connect before you can init your server.

**Here is an example:**

```
#define WIFI_TIMEOUT 5000
#define WIFI_DEBUG true

/*
  This function will wait for a wifi to connect.
  If the connection takes more then WIFI_TIMEOUT it will return 
  false, otherwise returns true.
*/
boolean connectWifi(){
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    long wifiConnStartMS = millis();
    #if WIFI_DEBUG
        Serial.printf("\nConnecting to: %s...",ssid);
    #endif
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(200);
        if( millis() - wifiConnStartMS >= WIFI_TIMEOUT ){
            #if WIFI_DEBUG
                Serial.println("\nTimeout on wifi connection. Wrong credentials?");
            #endif
            return false; 
        }
    }
    #if WIFI_DEBUG
        Serial.printf("\nWiFi Connected to: %s\n",ssid);
    #endif
    return true;
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);

    if( connectWifi() ){
        // Begin your server...
    }
}
```